# Does 4-wheel alignment involve taking wheels off?

Tags: alignment

I was wondering if a 4-wheel alignment involves taking off all the wheels.  I called NTB to check whether their wheel alignment includes tire rotation and they said it didn't.  But if they have to take all the wheels off, why would it matter which wheel they put on which rotor, i.e. doesn't make any difference to them?  If they can do it without taking the wheels off, then I would understand.

Answer (score 9):

An alignment does not require removing the wheels. The equipment is attached to the wheels while they are in place. I often wondered about the shops that will do a free brake inspection but then charge $20 for tire rotation.

Comment: I'd really love to know how my local dealer comes up with the "brake % remaining" numbers they give me after an oil change.  They do not remove the wheels.  Yet, the numbers are accurate...  It's easy enough to get access to the caliper through the wheel with a tool, but you can't see anything there.  Perhaps they have a feeler gauge of some type?

Comment: @BrianKnoblauch It's easy to see with most wheels with just a flashlight, others take a mirror, and a few take a small video scope.